# Как прочитать медиа файл из raw папки (native)?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

Сейчас у меня есть нативная имплементация которая использует `JNI`. Медиа файлы сейчас (для примера) лежат тут `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my_app.debug/files/Models/my_media_file.mp4` то в дириктории самого приложения. Для того, чтоб начать читать медиа файл мне нужно вызвать `JNI` метод и передать ему этот путь к файлу. Нативный метод откроет этот файл, вот метод

```
bool Decoder::InitFromFile(std::string const &filename)
{
    m_file.open(filename, std::ios::binary);
    if (!m_file.is_open())
    {
        return false;
    }
...
}
```

Так все работает, но сейчас мне нужно прочитать файл из `raw` папки, теперь, чтоб получить путь к файлу я делаю так

```
fun foo()
{
...
        val path = "android.resource://" + activity!!.packageName + "/" + R.raw.my_media_file
        val uri = Uri.parse(path)
        JNIImplementation.InitFromFile(uri.path)
...
}
```

Но теперь `uri = android.resource://com.my_app.debug/2131492865` и `uri.path = /2131492865`.

Проблема в том, что если передаю `uri.path` как путь к файлу в этот метод `InitFromFile` то я получаю ошибку, так как я не могу открыть файл по такому пути `/2131492865`

Я так понимаю, что должен быть способ передать `AssertManager`  имя ресурса и открывать файл из `raw или assert` дириктории (нативно)

Как это сделать?

Или может есть путь, как сделать так, чтоб медиа файл был `build-in`, но при этом можно было бы получить к нему путь так, чтоб можно было открыть как файл? Я имею ввиду, смотреть на файл не как на ресурс, а как на стандартный файл который можно открыть с помощью моего метода (по его пути)?

Answer (score 0):

Точно не скажу как это решается на уровне NDK, но на уровне Java это решается так:

Полученная ссылка `Uri` разрешается через `ContentResolver`, типа `content.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)`, в итоге вы получаете `InputStream`, пользуясь которым уже можно прочитать сам контент файла.

Очевидно вам надо такой же фокус проделать и в NDK.